# Apache 2.2 and php-fpm directory configuration

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

I have installed apache 2.2 and php-fpm. In httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/local.site/public_html

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/php5-fcgi/">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
       Allow from ::1
       #Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/local.site/public_html>
       Order Allow,Deny
       Deny from all
</Directory>
```

How to allow to execute *.php and html files, but deny directories listening? Because, whatever I do, it is denied /php5-fcgi/, *.php, or it is allowed to read directories.

Comment: `-Indexes` to deny directory listing

Comment: Yes, what I should do with these directives, in order to make web server more secure. Because now it denied everything. By the way, I utilize CentOS 6.7, and in virtual host I wrote FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization